# how long does a session last in Redmine (Ruby on Rails) and change that duration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, redmine

when creating a session in Redmine

> config/application.rb

```
config.session_store :cookie_store, :key => '_redmine_session'
```

how long does the default session last?

and how do i change the default length? (for example to last one hour)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Redmine` stores session data in a cookie (as is the default in Rails apps in general). As such, there is no actual session data stored on the server.

The session data in the `cookies` are cryptographically signed in a way that actual end users can not change them. However, the information is visible to them which means that you shouldn't store sensitive (or large amounts of) data in there.

Coincidentally, this is also why you need to create the session secret when you first install Redmine. It is used to sign the cookie and to ensure that the data wasn't tampered with.

For Time Setting Check this  **https://github.com/redmine/redmine/blob/master/config/settings.yml**

Comment: thanks for your fast answer Gagen,
what i don't understand is when looking at the cookies resources, 
i see what you were talking about:
Name: _redmine_session, Value: hash of some sort, Expires / Max-Age: Session.

is there no way that the session will be ever closed (after a long time)?

Comment: check it out this https://github.com/redmine/redmine/blob/master/config/settings.yml

Comment: So...if Redmine stores session data in a cookie and there are two BitNami Redmine stacks running parallel on the same server, how come with the same URL on a different port, one Redmine version overrides the other.  The only way to access the other Redmine instance is to stop the Bitnami services on the Redmine currently running in the browser:    https://community.bitnami.com/t/two-bitnami-redmine-stacks-in-one-machine-windows/20558/18?u=joshyates1980